# How to do inner join in django

Tags: python, django, orm

I have three tables as below

CurrentDiscount -

```
ItemID  | DiscountID
-----------------------
 1      |  2
 4      |  8
```

AvailableDiscounts -

```
DiscountID  |   ItemID  | Description
--------------------------------------
1           |   1       | '30% off'
2           |   1       | '10% off'
3           |   1       | 'Buy One Get One' 
4           |   4       | '30% off'
5           |   4       | 'Upto 20% off'
6           |   4       | '30% off'
```

Discount ID is auto generated.

I would like to fetch Objects of current Available discounts like below -

```
select AvailableDiscounts.* from CurrentDiscount Inner Join AvailableDiscounts Using (DiscountID)
```

I want list of AvailableDiscounts objects.
What will be the Django query for this ?

```
class CurrentDiscount(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, primary_key=True)
    discount = models.ForeignKey(AvailableDiscounts)

class AvailableDiscounts(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    description = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Please update your question with your models.

Answer (score 1):

```
current_discounts = CurrentDiscount.objects.all()
```

In view

```
for ds in current_discounts:
  print ds.discount.description
```

In html

```
{% for ds in current_discounts %}
  {{ds.discount.description}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of forignkey. You can set a forignkeyModel, and use

```
c = CurrentDiscount.objects.all()
c.availableDiscounts_set.all()
```